# Same 'smb.conf' on two server: but different results ? (username/password prompted on one)

Tags: samba

I have a working 'public' / 'guest' Samba Share on one Linux machine; the '/etc/samba/smb.conf' looks like this:

```
[shared]
comment = Shared Directory
writable = yes
read only = no
create mask = 0644
directory mask = 0755
path= /home/myuser/shared
browseable = yes
guest ok =yes
```

The *same* smb.conf file was copied to another Linux machine; and Samba was restarted.

The original server allows me to access it without providing a username or password; the new server always requests a username and password (and actually every combination of what I think it should be doesn't work in any case).

Is there another setting somewhere else other than 'smb.conf' I need to change ?

I want this share to be public, with no username/password necessary - ie, to behave like the original server where I copied the 'smb.conf' from.

Additional: I just run a 'testparm -v' and see at least the following differences :

The original server has this in the [global] section:

```
security = SHARE
```

Whereas the new server has this:

```
security = USER
```

But I have also set up 'security = USER' (I'm using a copy of 'smb.conf' afterall) in the 'smb.conf' file on the new machine ?

Is there an over-riding configuration here ?

UPDATE:

Ah : looks like I am using 'samba4' here - which apparently has deprecated the 'security share' mode.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1962617

....
There are several posts out there that state that doing:

```
map to guest = Bad User
```

Should emulate the 'share' facility - but it doesn't seem to work for me.
(I'm attaching with a Windows7 client; and I have added a 'samba' user).

(Also: my config had 'bad user' - lowercase)......

Answer (score 0):

OK - I have a solution which works for me (but is still not ideal, see below)

1. I added a 'samba' user like this:

   sudo smbpasswd -a arthur

Where 'arthur' matches my Windows Domain Account Name (without the 'domain\' prefix).

Also it seems that I have to set the password for this to match my Windows Domain Account Password.

The reason I (guess) did this: was I noticed that my Windows7 dialogue was asking for a DOMAIN user; and *seems* to be both validating my domain-username/password with Windows; and *then* passes the same credentials to the Samba Server.

So : this kinda works for me; but isn't ideal - because:

1. Every user will need to do this (the idea was to *share* this directory once; but looks like each user will need to add in their own username - since I don't know their passwords).
2. My Domain Password will presumably go out of sync with the Samba User Password at some point.